# Getting front page title in the middle of the page when using \thispagestyle{empty}

Tags: spacing, titles

For front page of the document I'm using `\thispagestyle{empty}`. But this command put the title on the very first row. I want to put the title in the middle to the page. I tried with `\vspace{50mm}` but it does not effect the behavior of `\thispagestyle{empty}`. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please make a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that shows the problem. Without this it would be only a quiz finding out, which class you are using and how you make your front page. I've tried classes `article` and `report` but at both `\thispagestyle{empty}` doesn't influence the position of the result of `\maketitle`. Maybe you simply search for option `titlepage`. But I really don't know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following would put the title into the middle of an empty page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}\centering
\vspace*{\fill}
\LARGE Title
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Schweinebacke's answer solves the problem well, but it might be worth pointing out what was going wrong originally.

First, page styles and in particular `\thispagestyle{empty}` are to do with the headers and footers, not body text; the effect of this command is to get rid of the automatic page number. Second, `\vspace`s are discarded at the top or bottom of pages unless, as Schweinebacke has done, you use the starred version of the command.

Comment: One could also add some non-printed "anchor" (like `\mbox{}` or `\null`) and use `\vfill`.